# Headphones with iPhone 6 protection case

Tags: headphones, case

I have a small protection case around my iPhone 6 and my headphones can't be plugged perfectly. Anybody knows a very thin case to protect my iPhone without having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Probably be cheaper to borrow a needle file & ream out the cover's headphone hole a bit;
or even a simple nail-file & chamfer the edge of the headphone plug itself.